# React-Native Navigator: Can't add a component using Navigator

Tags: navigation, react-native

I am trying to build a small app with a few different screens using Navigator. The problem I am running into is importing different components in my view.  Here is my index.android.js
           **index.ANDROID.JS**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
   AppRegistry,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
   Navigator,
   TouchableHighlight
 } from 'react-native';


 import Menu from './src/menu';
 import Home from './src/addWord';
 var JapaneseProjectShare2 = React.createClass({


   renderScene(route, navigator) {
    console.log(route);
     if(route.name == 'menu') {
       return <Menu navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />
     }
     if(route.name == 'Home') {
       return <Home navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />
     }
     if(route.name == 'AddWords') {
      console.log('display add words');
       return <Home navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />
     }
   },
   render() {
       return (
         <Navigator

           initialRoute={{ name: 'menu' }}
           renderScene={ this.renderScene } />
       )
     }
   });

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 80
  },
   heading: {
    fontSize:22,
    marginBottom:10
  },
  button: {
    height:60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#efefef',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize:20
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('JapaneseProjectShare2', () => JapaneseProjectShare2);
```

This next class is my Menu class. My menu class has a list of options that a user can click. For example a user clicks on Addwords option and he should be navigated to that page. It throws an error here: Minified React error #130.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Container, Header,TouchableHighlight, Title,StyleSheet, Content,Icon,Card,CardItem, InputGroup, Input,Text,View} from 'native-base';


var Menu  = React.createClass({


    getInitialState(){
        return({
            menu:['AddWords','View List','DeleteWords','EditWords','Dictionary']
        })
    },
    _navigate(name) {
        this.props.navigator.push({
        name: name,
         passProps: {
            name: name
         }
       })
     },
    displayMenu(menu){
            let intro = 'Please select an option';
            return(
                menu.map((menu,index)=>{
                    return(
                     <Container style={{backgroundColor:'#565051'}}>    
                                <Content>
                                    <Card>
                                      <CardItem button onPress={ () => this.navigateToMenu(this.state.menu[index])}>                 
                                            <Icon name='ios-list'/>              
                                           <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{menu}</Text>                                   
                                      </CardItem>

                                 </Card>
                               </Content>
                    </Container>

                    )

                })
            )

        },
        navigateToMenu(index){
            this._navigate(index)

        },
    render(){
        return(
        <Container style={{backgroundColor:'#565051'}}> 
            <Header>
                 <Title>Menu</Title>
            </Header>
            <Content>
                {this.displayMenu(this.state.menu)}
            </Content>
        </Container>    
        // <View>
        // {this.displayMenu(this.state.menu)}
        // </View>

        )
    }   

    })

module.exports = Menu;
```

My goal is to have the user click on the menu class and be brought to the correct screen. For example, the user would click on AddWord which then he would be navigated to that screen. I am able to successfully do this if I keep everything in the same file. If I put AddWord class inside of index.android.js then it works as I would suspect. The problem is that when I try to separate the files I get the error message. Can anyone point out any mistakes I am making in my first attempt at this. Thanks.

```
   **AddWord.js**

import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Container, Header,TouchableHighlight, Title,StyleSheet, Content,Icon,Card,CardItem, InputGroup, Input,Text,View} from 'native-base';


var addWords = React.createClass({
         render(){
           return(){
             <View>
           <Text>Testing</Text>
             <View>
           }      
        }              



            })

module.exports = addWords;
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you name the AddWord class `AddWord`.. it's called Menu now. I also don't see the difference between that file and Menu.js?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to me.  I tried to use the word AddWord and still no success. Is there an example or tutorial that could help me figure this out?

Comment: Here's something that might help? https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.5cis5s1i9

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the react-native router flux library.

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

To use this create your component scenes in the landing page like index.ios/android.js create scenes like

```
 <Router>
    <Scene key="landing_page" component={LandingPage} initial={true}> </Scene>
   <Scene key='firstPage' component={FirstPage} ></Scene>
   <Scene key='secondPage' component={SecondPage} ></Scene>
 </Router>
```

In your menu.js file create a touchable component as

```
 <TouchableHighligh onPress={()=>{Actions.first()}}>
   <View>
     <Text>Click here to go to first page
     </Text>
   </View>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

Similarly you can go to the second page.

Its very easy to use. Good Luck